# crossfilter.all() not working as per the docs + cf.size works

Tags: crossfilter

as per the [docs](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_all) I cannot get `cf.all()` to work

I am using this as an example [here](http://animateddata.co.uk/articles/crossfilter/) in the console in the broswer.

This is what i see in the console.

```
cf
Object {}
cf.all()
VM1818:1 Uncaught TypeError: cf.all is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1818:1
cf.size()
2692
```

I can get `cf.size()` to work but not `cf.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crossfilter.all` was added in the version 1.4 alphas. The page you are looking at uses version 1.3.12, so it doesn't include that method. I've updated the documentation to reflect this.

Comment: tks you for that. can you provide a link to 1.4? the best I could find is [1.3.12.](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crossfilter)

Comment: Releases are here: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/releases  You can grab in from NPM or Bower as well, where it is the 'crossfilter2' project.